# writing functions for animations in android

Tags: android, function, class, animation

I have 4 function for animations like this

```
SetAlphaAnimation
SetRotateAnimation
SetTranslateAnimation
SetScaleAnimation
```

For example:

```
static public void setAlphaAnimation(View img,float FROM,float TO,int Offset,int Duration)
{
    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(FROM, TO); 
    alpha.setStartOffset(Offset);
    alpha.setDuration(Duration); 
    img.startAnimation(alpha);
}
```

and, when I use these functions like this,

```
    MF.setTranslateAnimation(img,100,500,2000,3000);
    MF.setAlphaAnimation(img, 0.0, 1.0, 2000,3000);
```

the lastest animation just work. I know that I should define `AnimationSet` and work with it, but I want use functions.

Note that the functions in another class and I can't define Global variable.

Any Idea???

Comment: A view can only have one animation at a time. If you need to animate several parameters, you need to create an AnimationSet, as you point out.

Comment: Yeah, this is my problem...